# FXML/CSS: Button with image in center and text in bottom

Tags: css, javafx, fxml

I have a button with an icon and text and I can't figure out how to place the icon in the center and the text in the bottom left of the button. This is what it looks like right now:

```
<Button text="Text" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" prefWidth="135" prefHeight="110" style="-fx-background-color: rgb(176,30,0); -fx-text-fill: rgb(255,255,255); -fx-alignment: BOTTOM_LEFT;">
    <graphic>
        <ImageView>
            <Image url="file:///....png"/>
        </ImageView>
    </graphic>
</Button>
```

Two things I've tried, which haven't been working:
1. Giving the ImageView a separate alignment attribute.
2. Placing a VXbox inside the button and the imageView as well as label with text inside the VBox.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`contentDisplay`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#contentDisplayProperty) property controls the position of the graphic relative to the text. The [`alignment`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html#alignmentProperty) property controls the position of the overall content.

So

```xml
<Button text="Text" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" prefWidth="135" prefHeight="110" 
    alignment="BOTTOM_LEFT" contentDisplay="TOP" 
    style="-fx-background-color: rgb(176,30,0); -fx-text-fill: rgb(255,255,255);">
```

or some similar combination, should work.

If you prefer to set these in CSS, `-fx-alignment: bottom-left; -fx-content-display: top ;` will do the same.

The `contentDisplay` property doesn't quite give you full control over the positioning of the graphic; you may need to use the idea you proposed of placing a container with the image view and a label as the graphic. In this case, you probably want an alignment of center. A `BorderPane` would probably be closer to what you need than a `VBox`:

```xml
<Button GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" prefWidth="135" prefHeight="110" style="-fx-background-color: rgb(176,30,0); -fx-text-fill: rgb(255,255,255); -fx-alignment: center;">
    <graphic>
        <BorderPane>
            <center>
                <ImageView>
                    <Image url="file:///....png"/>
                </ImageView>
            </center>
            <bottom>
                <Label text="Text"/>
            </bottom>
        </BorderPane>
    </graphic>
</Button>
```

You may also need to experiment with setting the preferred size of the border pane, to make it fill the area allocated to the button.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, alignment="CENTER" places the image at the center of the text instead of the very center of the button. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Varest In that case, you probably need to revert to the idea of using a container as the graphic (see update for suggestion). You could also experiment, e.g., with wrapping the image view in a `HBox` with preferred width and alignment set on the `HBox`.

Comment: Your second suggestion worked perfectly, thank you very much!